# Erro 500 ao usar Slim Framework com Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

Estou desenvolvendo um simples **website**, com Slim Framework e Twig para template *engine*, só que esta retornando o **erro 500** no navegador, esse é o conteúdo do meu arquivo `index.php` (na raiz do projeto):

```
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

// Create container
$container = new \Slim\Container;

// Register component on container
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('app/views', [
        'cache' => 'app/storage/cache'
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $c['router'],
        $c['request']->getUri()
    ));

    return $view;
};

// Create app
$app = new \Slim\App($container);

// Routes
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('index.twig', ['app' => $app]);
})->name('home');

// Run app
$app->run();
```

a minha estrutura de pastas está assim:

```
app
  |__views
  |__storage
           |__cache
vendor
     |__twig
     |__slim
     |__psr
     |__composer
assets
     |__css
     |__js
     |__img
     |__fonts
```

Segui as instruções nesse exemplo: h[ttp://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/features/templates.html)

Gostaria de renderizar a *view* "home", mas apenas retorna:

> Erro 500

Comment: No arquivo principal coloque, `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: verifiquei o log do apache e esta escrito isso: ```Class 'Slim\\Container' not found```

Comment: Como está seu arquivo .htaccess? O erro pode está nele.

Comment: tá sem .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Pelo inicio do seu código parece que você está utilizando o Slim Framework v3, mas pela forma que criou a *route*, ali é a forma do v2.

Vou presumir que está usando o Slim v3.

**Como está sem .htaccess, primeiro crie ele:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Caso não esteja usando apache pode encontrar os códigos para outros *webservers* em http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html

**Altere seu código da route para:**

```
// Routes
$app->get( '/', function ( $request, $response, $args ) {
    return $this->view->render( $response, 'index.twig', [ 'app', $this ] );
} )->setName( 'home' );
```

Houve mudanças consideráveis entre o Slim v2 e o Slim v3, destacaram as principais na documentação em http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html

**Complemento**

Para habilitar o *debug* no Slim v3, adicione ao *container*

```
$container['settings']['displayErrorDetails'] = true;
```

Ainda estou estudando um pouco essa nova versão, mas espero ter ajudado.